# How to properly use RouterOutlet with submodule without disposing

Tags: flutter, router-outlet, flutter-modular

I am using flutter_modular in my current project. using Modular.to.navigate on BottomNavBarItem click it disposes Child Module that inside previous tab
I need to keep all modules undisposed because need each route in routerOutlet to keep his state and not dispose.
Need to keep tab pages state alive without disposing but without indexedstack

we are importing all routeoutlet modules in appmodule also with export true flag but it doesnt work with latest flutter_modular
as mentioned here https://github.com/Flutterando/modular/blob/e7cdfdb3935dc6b5e543b16a164ecf06c2e98446/doc/docs/flutter_modular/module.md

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.